# CloudBees application snapshots

Tags: cloudbees

CloudBees run@cloud service stores application snapshots every time you deploy a new version of an application so that you can easily switch back to using an older version, when needed. I've noticed that all snapshots are there and when applications (like in our case) are deployed very often, the snapshot list tends to grow very large.

So, the question goes: Does this matter? I mean, is the storage space that the snapshots need calculated against the available storage space that we have on our current subscription level? If not, I don't mind having them all around, but if yes, then I'd like to write some scripts to clean them up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not calculated against the available storage space that we have on your current subscription level. AFAIK CloudBees doesn't track any storage space limit on the snapshots that they generate everytime that you deploy a new version of your application.

Comment: Maybe this has changed recently, but we got a quota error and it *was* caused by the large amount of old snapshots. Deleting them fixed the problem.